# Where is the io library defined in Go?

Tags: go

Specifically, where are io.reader and io.writer interfaces defined?

Comment: If you have these kinds of questions in the future and you have a checkout of the Go source, godoc is your friend. `godoc -q io.Reader` will give you the declaration location. `godoc -src io Reader` will give you the exported definition and documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `io` package:

http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader
http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer